# openCV Won't copy to image after changed color ( opencv and c++ )

Tags: c++, opencv

I am a beginner at opencv.
I have this task:

1. Make a new image
2. Put a certain image in it at 0,0
3. Convert the certain image to gray scale
4. put the grayscaled image next to it ( at 300, 0 )

This is what I did.
I have a class imagehandler that has constructor and all the functions.

```
cv::Mat m_image
```

is the member field.

Constructor to make new image:

```
imagehandler::imagehandler(int width, int height)
: m_image(width, height, CV_8UC3){


}
```

Constructor to read image from file:

```
imagehandler::imagehandler(const std::string& fileName)
: m_image(imread(fileName, CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR))
{
if(!m_image.data)
{
    cout << "Failed loading " << fileName << endl;
}

}
```

This is the function to convert to grayscale:

```
void imagehandler::rgb_to_greyscale(){

cv::cvtColor(m_image, m_image, CV_RGB2GRAY);

}
```

This is the function to copy paste image:

```
//paste image to dst image at xloc,yloc
void imagehandler::copy_paste_image(imagehandler& dst, int xLoc, int yLoc){

cv::Rect roi(xLoc, yLoc, m_image.size().width, m_image.size().height);
cv::Mat imageROI (dst.m_image, roi);

m_image.copyTo(imageROI);
 }
```

Now, in the main, this is what I did :

```
imagehandler CSImg(600, 320); //declare the new image
imagehandler myimg(filepath);

myimg.copy_paste_image(CSImg, 0, 0);
CSImg.displayImage(); //this one showed the full colour image correctly
myimg.rgb_to_greyscale();
myimg.displayImage(); //this shows the colour image in GRAY scale, works correctly
myimg.copy_paste_image(CSImg, 300, 0);
CSImg.displayImage(); // this one shows only the full colour image at 0,0 and does NOT show the greyscaled one at ALL!
```

What seems to be the problem? I've been scratching my head for hours on this one!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the following problem:

At the constructor instead of

```
m_image(width, height, CV_8UC3){}
```

you should write

```
{  
  m_image.create(width, height, CV_8UC3);  
}
```

instead and don't worry about the default construction.

REMARKS:

- Im not sure cvtColor works properly with the same Mat as input and output, I think it is safer to change it to `Mat temp; cvtColor(m_image, temp, CV_...); m_image=temp;`
- You can check if the image is empty by calling `m_image.empty()` not by checking `!m_image.data`. Otherwise you can't be sure. The pointer m_image.data also can be stale due to refcounted resource management.
- from your earlier question, where I saw a custom destructor: you don't need that, no worries there.