# Major memory leaks when using opencv ( opencv and c++ )

Tags: c++, opencv

I have had a homework for my Systems Programming course.
All went fine without any memory leaks, until I used opencv (still a beginner at it).

Basically, I have a students class and courses class and I must assign the correct type of student (Computer Science student, PG student..) to the correct courses (Elective and PG/CS courses).

I did all what I had to do, and now the final step is to show images of who graduated in color and images of who did not graduate in greyscale. Did it all.

I made an imagehandler class that handles opening the images, saving images to file, initializing new images and all the functions like convert to RGB and convert to GreyScale..

This imagehandler class has the field of the image which is a:

```
cv::Mat m_image;
```

Now, inside the student class, I made that each student has an imagehandler object, which I store his image into it.

I even did a destructor in the imagehandler class:

```
imagehandler::~imagehandler(){
   m_image.release();
}
```

Before I started with the opencv step (before I even installed opencv and embedded what I needed to do in my code) I had no memory leaks at all.
After I programmed (and all worked) the opencv step, I had major leaks.

Here's the logfile of valgrind (had to put it in a paste bin because it is too big to be here):
 [valgrind.log](http://sebsauvage.net/paste/?96f8c3c8effc4ef2#lutPwjh8nBzZCCfF+1VwlQUpYl3u0RrTl1TqpNr3AKM=)

The errors are mainly when I read an image, save an image, resize image, convert to rgb or greyscale... all opencv related leaks.

Comment: When you click the link of valgrind log, it tells you wrong key. Try copy pasting the link! sorry for the inconvenience!

Comment: Not that you shouldn't try to solve this, but if all you need to do is generate your images and then presumably terminate the program, does a memory leak really even matter for this assignment?

Comment: Of course, it is a Systems Programming course. An essential subject is memory management and we are instructed to manage it correctly, we should not have any leaks.

Comment: you could prepare a full working code to demonstrate the problem and share. that way we could help better.

Comment: The OP updated his question in a new question. I think it is better to keep the [newer question with the code in this case](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13478941/opencv-wont-copy-to-image-after-changed-color-opencv-and-c/13523334#13523334)

Answer (score 0):

I have met this problem before and I sloved this by change the version of OpenCV.I use opencv-2.4.13 now and has no problem of memory leak.The problem version is opencv-3.0.00.